# How to properly link created functions between cuda and cpp files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda, mex

I am writing a MATLAB **.mex** library to run with c++ and CUDA. In both **.cu** and **.cpp** files I have to write:

`extern "C" void myFunction(float* variable1,float* variable2);`

to compile with Visual Studio 2015. The definition of `myFunction` is in the **.cu** file and I call it in the **.cpp**. It is already working, however I want to organize it better and make it easier to fix something in the future.

**My question is:** Is there a way to create a header file to link this function in both files so I don't need to explicitly write `extern "C"` in both of them?

Comment: Given everything will be compiled with C++ linkage, you don't need to use `extern "C"` at all, so I really don't understand what your question is in this case

Comment: I just copied `extern "C"` from a working example (and it was working). I just did what @MariaChiara replied and worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to create a header file, for example call it `myFile.h`, in there you put function declaration **only**:

```
void myFunction(float* variable1,float* variable2);
```

Then in your `myFile.cu` you put the function definition:

```
void myFunction(float* variable1,float* variable2){
    std::cout << "Hi! I'm a function!" << std::endl;
}
```

Finally you have to include your header both in `myFile.cu` and `myFile.cpp`:

```
#include <cosFutStr.h>
```

In that way you'll have the function definition in `myFile.cu` and you'll be able to call `myFunction` from `myFile.cpp`.
As talonmies said in comments, given that you'll compile your sources with C++ linkage, everything will be linked in the proper way without the use of `extern "C"`.
But I think this is more a C++ question, than a CUDA one.

Comment: That worked! Before, I was writing the function declaration on the header with the `extern "C"` and VS was not compiling at all.

Comment: If you agree, I think you should edit your question to remove unrelated tags.
(IMO surely mex and maybe cuda too, since they aren't the focus of your problem)

Comment: even though there are not straight related to the topic, maybe someone in the future has the same question and can reach this topic. I have seen some people using `extern "C"` with mex files and CUDA.  So, it might be helpful for them.